# How to return a collection of JSON documents as a JSON array

Tags: json, marklogic, serverside-javascript

I have a collection of JSON documents in MarklLogic which I want to return to an API call as a JSON Array.

```
fn.collection('my-users')
```

Returns a sequence of JSON docs, I need a valid JSON object, an array. I am doing this in serverside java script, pushing to a new empty array().

No real example documentation to my knowledge, only in XQuery some examples.Google keeps referring to this very high level documentation [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/app-dev/json)

```
var myArray = [];

for (d of fn.collection('my-users')){
  myArray.push(d);
}

myArray
```

Do I need to loop over each item in the sequence to push to an array or is there a more elegant/quicker solution?

hugo

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for.  What should the output look like?  Do you want a JSON representation for each document?  Are the documents in JSON or XML?  Also for a full list of server-sider JavaScript functions with examples, go to http://docs.marklogic.com and select the Section "Server-Side JavaScript APIs" in the upper-left pane.  Most XQuery functions are also available for server-side JavaScript.

Comment: fn.collection('my-users').toArray() was what I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterables are from ES6 and are (from what I understand), one of the only things carried over for the initial release of SJS along with sub-sequences.

The reason for these is so that you get the same behaviour as you would get with sequences and sub-sequences in xQuery. (different notation in the two languages, but identical behaviour)

If there were a full implementation of ES6, then the answer for you would be `Array.from(iteratable)`

However, without that feature, then I think you are using the most efficient way. But be careful that you don't suck your entire database into memory with the pushing from iterator to array.

I am curious of your use-case for needing them in an array actually..

-David

Comment: It's actually *iterable*, not *iterator*. The distinction is subtle, but important. Until we support `Array.from()` (which is upcoming), there’s also the `.toArray()` method on `ValueIterator.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Justin. "(which is upcoming)" sounds exciting - can;t wait to see what else is on the way related to SJS...  @Hugo - see Justin's comment regarding .toArray()...

Comment: Justin's answer is what my intention was. So I'll accept David's answer then.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to return them as a JSON array, you're doing the right thing.  There's no more elegant/quicker solution that I know of.  But if you're looking for a more optimized / high performance way, try [REST extensions](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_29656) which will turn a sequence of documents into a multi-part HTTP response.

Here's an example.  Given example.sjs with the contents:

```
function get(context, params) {
  return fn.collection('my-users')
}
exports.GET = get;
```

Installed like so:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X PUT -i \
  -H "Content-type: application/vnd.marklogic-javascript" \
  --data-binary @./example.sjs \
  http://localhost:8000/LATEST/config/resources/js-example
```

And the following docs inserted into the my-users collection (I assume you know how to insert these):

myuser.json

```
{"name":"Sue"}
```

myuser2.json

```
{"name":"Mary"}
```

myuser3.json

```
{"name":"Jane"}
```

myuser4.json

```
{"name":"Joe"}
```

You can call your rest extension like so:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin \
    http://localhost:8000/LATEST/resources/js-example
```

And you get the following multi-part http response:

```
--js-example-get-result
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 14

{"name":"Sue"}
--js-example-get-result
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 15

{"name":"Mary"}
--js-example-get-result
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 15

{"name":"Jane"}
--js-example-get-result
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 14

{"name":"Joe"}
--js-example-get-result--
```

Use your favorite client-side http library to accept that efficient response as an individual json document for each document.

I should add that there's no need for a REST extension if your requirements are this simple.  You could simply use the REST search endpoint:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin \
  -H accept:multipart/mixed \
  http://localhost:8000/LATEST/search?collection=my-users
```

and get a very similar multi-part http response.  I only provided the REST extension example since your question was about server-side javascript and I figured you might have additional requirements that require that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to loop. The following should help you for your need:

myArray.push(fn.doc(fn.collection('my-users')))